# Common rectifier (or source) to power testing equipments

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, diy, test-equipment

I was thinking of a design of an all-in-one box that contains a DIY Oscilloscope, a DIY frequency generator, a DIY bench-top power supply (by a buck converter), and a multimeter (broken out from the case and used as it is in the box). My current concept involves powering these individual components from a common transformer (to step down source plug voltage) and rectifier (needed for the oscilloscope, frequency generator, multimeter). Will it be a good idea to do that? Since all these components will involve noises in the source, can it affect the readings of the equipment significantly? Are there alternative ideas to achieve the same?

P.S. Since I am at the conceptualisation stage, any ideas for doing this (eg: having a autotransformer etc.) will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Doing this would imply that every device works on the same voltage rail as input. I think it could be easier to just start out looking at the individual sub-components and adding power supplies for them as necessary.

Comment: Yes, that would be the safest option but it would make the entire thing a little bulky. It would be better if that single rail works fine